# WSO2: Can IS access token be used for APIM access token for APIs for same users?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

When integrating the WSO2 Identity Server (5.6.0) and WSO2 APIM (2.5.0). I came across one scenario where I want the token which I am generating while logging into IS should be used also for invoking APIs in APIM which are created by the same user.

I am creating user in IS and it is getting reflected in APIM but the token which is generated for IS is getting saves in IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN of IS DB and for APIM while invoking any APIs for the same user, the token are getting saved in IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN of APIM.

I want to use the same token which was generated in IS to invoke APIs which the same user created in APIM.

Any guidance in this direction will help me to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a distributed deployment of APIM, you can use IS as the key manager node. The following document explains how to set it up.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager

This document explains (step 3) how to share databases between APIM and IS. You can use the same to achieve what you want.

In short, you need to configure IS to use the APIM DB (shared between 2 nodes) instead of its own IS DB.

You also have to map the Application in the API store to the OAuth app you have created in IS. See this doc for that.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Provisioning+Out-of-Band+OAuth+Clients

Comment: Thanks Bee.
I have been able to do that by creating UM_DB, REG_DB and AM_DB which are shared between APIM and IS but do you say that if we have to have same token for IS and APIM then both of them has to run in same server?

Comment: Sharing the DB is enough.

Comment: ok.. now when I am trying to create a new API token for a particular user, I am getting below error:

ERROR - AbstractKeyManager Can not create OAuth application  : DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://localhost:9445/services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService

Any suggestion pls

Comment: I am invoking the token from API store and this is the error message from backend.
9445 is the port where the IS is running in same server where APIM is

Comment: Did you follow the step 5 of the doc too? You don't have to. If you follow the entire doc (which is the best thing to do though), you need to use the IS as KM server instead of the pure IS server as mentioned in step 1. `IS as KM server = Pure IS server + KM features`

Comment: ok but my point is IS-KM is installed in same server where APIM is installed. But in API-Manager.xml file in conf directory, I am giving https://localhost:9445/services/ in APIKeyvalidator and AuthManager,I get that no services are not found in this EPR and the connection fails

Comment: I have created one user in WSO2 IS-KM and that user is available in APIM also to access publisher and store.
But when I trying to subscribe to an API from that user using access token from IS. its says unauthenticated request. Can you please check and help me

Comment: Can some one please tell me that scope apim:subscribe can be added to IS scopes.
As now when I am trying to invoke oauth token in IS it comes with default scope and that cannot be used to perform any restAPI operations in APIM.. Is there a way?

Comment: Did you pass the required scopes in the token request? Show me your request.